# Fetch CSS of posts

Tags: plugins, plugin-json-api

I am using JSON API plugin for fetching recent posts.Now I want to show them in my web as they are being displayed in wordpress.How can i get css of wordpress theme?

Comment: This is interesting question, but seems like it's better aimed at JSON API developers since it's likely specific to it and not WP in general.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that you will be able to duplicate a look of a wordpress page just by applying the CSS directly to the content as the CSS usually depends on the structure of the HTML containing the content and not only on the content itself.

But fetching the CSS by itself is easy, just fetch the whole page and use regex to find the urls of all the included CSS.

Comment: just done one ;)